# MySQL Access denied for root @ localhost

Tags: mysql, linux

I could see a lot of solutions in StackOverflow w.r.t this problem. I couldn't find out exact solution for my problem. Here are the things I tried.

I am using mysql  Ver 8.0.32-0ubuntu0.20.04.2 for Linux on x86_64 ((Ubuntu))

Initially my problem was I couldn't login to mysql since I forgot my root password

So I stopped mysql service

`sudo service mysql stop`

started safe mode

`sudo service mysql stop`

solved some intermediate error with

```
sudo mkdir -p /var/run/mysqld
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/run/mysqld
```

logged in with command
`mysql -u root`

After this I tried multiple possiblities like

Based on some research I found that My plugin is 'auth_socket', with which only the actual user can be logged into mysql. i.e If I want to log in to root@localhost, I have to root user. Or If I am a user of my machine say user1. To use auth_socket plugin, There should be a user named 'user1' in the user table of mysql. (Correct me if I am wrong)

1. So I changed my plugin to 'mysql_native_password' and tried setting password with PASSWORD('password') method. Looks like its not supported now in my version
2. So, I updated my plugin from 'mysql_native_password' to 'sha2_password' and tried setting my password with

```
UPDATE mysql.user SET authentication_string=SHA2('password', 256) where User='root';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Everything updated neat and clean

stopped safe mode by
`sudo killall -KILL mysqld_safe`

started mysql again
`sudo service start mysql`

Tried login with non-hashed password like
`mysql -u root -p 'password'`
Note - password was given in separate line , entering the command like this just for reference.

Still getting access denied. I tried multiple combination of hashing method and password. Like storing plain password with mysql_native_password plugin. Nothing worked

In some references I also found I may need to GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES to the user. But my server says it cannot be done on --skip-grant-tables mode. Pls help me on this

Comment: can you try uninstalling and installing mysql again? it might be in some weird state now. Not an expert though